Selenium chromedriver can't open url from database
For some reason the chromedriver cannot retrieve the data from a database. Instead you get the default "data:," webpage in the chrome addressfield.
The chromedriver is able to retrieve data from:

Directly with driver.get("example.com")
From variables with a hardcoded link: lnk = "example.com"
A list of links: links = {'test.com','example.com','google.com'}

but not when there's a database involved and trying to get the data with:
link = entries[0]['link']
I have tried:

SQLite3 and TinyDB as database options.
Both firefox and chromium with their respective drivers (chromedriver, geckodriver)
Printing the variable with the database entry, and gotten correct results before, after and in the opsLogin function.
Minimizing the options for the driver
Formatting the variable as a string with str()
Force encoding and decoding the result
Chromium and chromedrivers are updated.

This is running on a Raspberry pi 4, Rasbian 11 Bullseye, Python3
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import time
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

# Options to run clean kiosk mode and keep the browser alive.
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
option.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
option.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
option.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
#option.add_argument("--kiosk")
option.add_argument("--disable-password-manager-reauthentication")
option.add_argument('--disable-save-password-bubble')
option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
option.add_argument("--password-store=basic")
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2,"credentials_enable_service": False,"profile.password_manager_enabled": False,})
# Keep alive and disable automation pop-up
option.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=option)

# Initialize TinyDB
db = TinyDB('assets.json')
entries = db.all()

lnk = entries[0]['source']
usr = entries[0]['user']
pw = entries[0]['password']

def opsLogin(link, user, password):
    driver.get(link)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    username_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'login_username')
    username_field.send_keys(user)
    password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'login_password')
    password_field.send_keys(password)
    login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "submit")
    login.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)

opsLogin(lnk, usr, pw)


include exception thrown when using .get().  There are some validation checks there.
